# Does Volenti non fit injuria work?

Tags: european-union

There is [Volenti non fit injuria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volenti_non_fit_injuria).

I'm confused whether if there is app where users can offend each other (what is illegal), but it requires user consent while registering that he accepts all things that can be done here to him (hate etc.), then can that app work legally? Could offending in such an application be legal and without consequences?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all.  Are you asking about the interpretation or effect of the quoted passage, or some broader question about philosophical principles (which would be off topic)?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm asking whether if some app is illegal (here I assumed that e2e encryption is illegal) "for safety" and requires consent from user to give up the safety (and to use the application), then can it work legally?

Comment: It is certainly possible for a law to make an activity illegal even if all parties consent.  Prostitution is a typical example.  So it would depend on whether your hypothetical law was written in such a way.

Comment: So I can give more real world example. Insulting, hating is illegal. But if I there is some app that requires user consent while registering, that user is aware of things that can happen to him here, then can haters be punished? I understand your example with prostitution, but I have secretly hope that Internet is more libertarian (in sense of `Volenti non fit injuria`).

Comment: There are multiple examples, in multiple jurisdictions, that show FMOTL's pseudolaw concerning consent is neither above nor independent from the law.

Comment: Related Meta question: [Should questions about 'freemen' theories and other cod law be allowed?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/35069)

Comment: Again, if your hypothetical jurisdiction writes their hypothetical law in such a way that consent isn't a defense, and the law is otherwise constitutional, then it isn't a defense.  Full stop.  There is no overarching principle that could override it.

Comment: I edited my question and removed assumption about encryption. I used different example.

Comment: The US and the EU are quite different in this regard, I’d suggest you pick one.

Comment: Also "the Internet" is not a jurisdiction.  People are subject to the laws of their country in everything they do, including banging keys on a keyboard in their room.

Comment: Ok, I have edited title and tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Some people seem to believe that just because something happens 'in the internet' it is somehow outside normal jurisdictions.
  **Wrong.**
  In may be harder to investigate and prosecute crimes in the internet, but the laws apply all the same. There are some problems when it is unclear 'where in the world' something did happen -- in the jurisdiction of the perpetrator, the victim, or the service provider? But problems of jurisdiction apply e.g. to international fraud cases in the non-web-world as well.
- In many jurisdictions, the informed and voluntary consent makes *some* things legal which would otherwise be illegal.
  For instance, if two boxers get into the ring, it is understood that each of them did consent to be hit by the other. But usually two fighters could not legally agree to a fight to the death, because even if there are laws on assisted suicide, they do not apply to a fight.
- Insults, libel, and slander are not on the same level as homicide. There are jurisdictions where they are not prosecuted without the request of the victim. But an insult might also violate other laws, e.g. disturbing the peace. So don't bet on such an app unless you know *for sure* which jurisdictions are involved.